# Spring FTP Inbound vs Outbound Channel Adaptor

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

What is the difference between  Inbound Channel Adaptor and Outbound Channel Adaptor in Spring Integration FTP. Which one I should I use and when?

I read from documentation that outbound can send any type of file(like byte[], String, java.io.File) but Inbound is restricted for File type only. Is that only difference or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to read a [theory](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) first of all.

Any `Inbound` adapter is intended to get data from external system. `Outbound` - to put data. E.g. simple case: JDBC Inbound performs a `SELECT` from DB, Outbound - `INSERT`.

In case of FTP: the first one to read files from FTP, the last - to write them.