# Spring Integration - Inbound vs Outbound Channel Adapters

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

**What is the fundamental difference between inbound and outbound channel adapters?**

Any examples would be very helpful.

I have reviewed the Spring docs and this "directional" distinction is not clear to me.  I support an application that has an outbound-channel-adapter configured, but I find the behavior counter intuitive with the *outbound* label.  This adapter gets an external file, then *brings it in* to the application where we parse the file and persist the data.

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216293/spring-ftp-inbound-vs-outbound-channel-adaptor) question, but I wanted to focus more generally on channel adapters, and hopefully get more feedback!

Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you said it seems that your application uses an outbound gateway which is something different than a channel adapter. The gateway receives a message, does an outbound operation (which can also be retrieving a file) and returns a message. A channel adapter is only uni directional (no reply).

Comment: It uses a channel adapter.  What did I say indicative of a gateway?  I can correct my wording...  You can see the configuration at this sibling question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/29994253/2860319

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Channel adapters are for one-way integration (gateways are bidirectional).

Concretely, inbound adapters are at the beginning of a flow, outbound adapters terminate a flow. Flows are typically rendered (and conceptually thought of as flowing from left to right)...

```
inbound-c-a->someComponent->someOtherComponent->outbound-ca
```

(where `->` represents a channel).

There are two types of inbound channel adapters:

- `MessageProducer`s
- `MessageSource`s

`MessageProducer`s are termed "message-driven" i.e. they unilaterally produce messages in a completely asynchronous manner, as soon as they are started; examples are JMS message-driven adapter, TCP inbound channel adapter, IMAP Idle (mail) channel adapter, etc.

`MessageSource`s on the other hand are polled - a `poller` with some trigger causes the framework to ask the source for a message; the trigger can be on a fixed rate, cron expression etc. Examples are the (S)FTP adapters, Mail inbound adapter (POP3. IMAP).

Examples of outbound adapters are Mail outbound adapter (SMTP).

Gateways are two-way (request/reply).

Inbound gateways are where some external system sends a request and Spring Integration replies.

Outbound gateways are where Spring Integration makes the request and some external system replies.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: if this is the case why for amqp there is an inbound and an outbound gateway? I'm struggling connecting a pojo as a gateway to amqp request/reply queues

Comment: Yes; I suggest you ask a new question showing your code.

Comment: @GaryRussell: _Gateways are two-way_ you said. Would a server in a simple echo service considered two-way? 
In another words, in my simple echo example https://stackoverflow.com/q/55154418/1185845 would you recommend to use Gateway on 
both client *and* server side? No adapters necessary?

Comment: Yes; anything request/reply is a gateway; you would use adapters for fire and forget or receive and send no reply, or you can have collaborating adapters for request/reply as discussed in the documentation. I answered your question with some sample code.

Answer (score 6):

in and out are relative directions, it must have a base. in spring integration, the base is the Spring integration framework ( that can be looked as a message bus), the adapters put message into it are in, the adapters take message out from it are out.