# How to implement simple echo socket service in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: java, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ip

Please,
could you help with implementation of a simple, echo style, Heartbeat TCP socket service in Spring Integration DSL? More precisely how to plug Adapter/Handler/Gateway to `IntegrationFlows` on the client and server side. Practical examples are hard to come by for Spring Integration DSL and TCP/IP client/server communication.

I think, I nailed most of the code, it's just that bit about plugging everything together in the `IntegrationFlow`.

There is an sample *echo service* in SI examples, but it's written in the "old" XML configuration and I really struggle to transform it to the configuration by code.

My Heartbeat service is a simple server waiting for client to ask "status", responding with "OK".

No `@ServiceActivator`, no `@MessageGateways`, no proxying, everything explicit and verbose; driven by a plain JDK scheduled executor on client side; server and client in separate configs and projects.

**HeartbeatClientConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class HeartbeatClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboudChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel inboundChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 7777);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter(
            TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageChannel inboundChannel) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter.setOutputChannel(inboundChannel); // ???
        heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter.setClientMode(true);
        return heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler(
            TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        heartbeatSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return heartbeatSendingMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow heartbeatClientFlow(
            TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter,
            TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler,
            MessageChannel outboudChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(outboudChannel) // ??????
                .// adapter ???????????
                .// gateway ???????????
                .// handler ???????????
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeartbeatClient heartbeatClient(
            MessageChannel outboudChannel,
            PollableChannel inboundChannel) {
        return new HeartbeatClient(outboudChannel, inboundChannel);
    }
}
```

**HeartbeatClient**

```
public class HeartbeatClient {
    private final MessageChannel outboudChannel;
    private final PollableChannel inboundChannel;
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HeartbeatClient.class);

    public HeartbeatClient(MessageChannel outboudChannel, PollableChannel inboundChannel) {
        this.inboundChannel = inboundChannel;
        this.outboudChannel = outboudChannel;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void initializaAfterContextIsReady(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        log.info("Starting Heartbeat client...");
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    log.info("Sending Heartbeat");
                    outboudChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("status"));
                    Message<?> message = inboundChannel.receive(1000);
                    if (message == null) {
                        log.error("Heartbeat timeouted");
                    } else {
                        String messageStr = new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                        if (messageStr.equals("OK")) {
                            log.info("Heartbeat OK response received");
                        } else {
                            log.error("Unexpected message content from server: " + messageStr);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

**HeartbeatServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class HeartbeatServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboudChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel inboundChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(7777);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter(
            TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageChannel outboudChannel) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter.setOutputChannel(outboudChannel);
        return heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler(
            TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        heartbeatSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return heartbeatSendingMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow heartbeatServerFlow(
            TcpReceivingChannelAdapter heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter,
            TcpSendingMessageHandler heartbeatSendingMessageHandler,
            MessageChannel outboudChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(heartbeatReceivingMessageAdapter) // ???????????????
                .handle(heartbeatSendingMessageHandler) // ???????????????
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeartbeatServer heartbeatServer(
            PollableChannel inboundChannel, 
            MessageChannel outboudChannel) {
        return new HeartbeatServer(inboundChannel, outboudChannel);
    }
}
```

**HeartbeatServer**

```
public class HeartbeatServer {
    private final PollableChannel inboundChannel;
    private final MessageChannel outboudChannel;
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HeartbeatServer.class);

    public HeartbeatServer(PollableChannel inboundChannel, MessageChannel outboudChannel) {
        this.inboundChannel = inboundChannel;
        this.outboudChannel = outboudChannel;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void initializaAfterContextIsReady(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        log.info("Starting Heartbeat");
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Message<?> message = inboundChannel.receive(1000);
                    if (message == null) {
                        log.error("Heartbeat timeouted");
                    } else {
                        String messageStr = new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                        if (messageStr.equals("status")) {
                            log.info("Heartbeat received");
                            outboudChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("OK"));
                        } else {
                            log.error("Unexpected message content from client: " + messageStr);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Bonus question**

Why channel can be set on TcpReceivingChannelAdapter (inbound adapter) but not TcpSendingMessageHandler (outbound adapter)?

**UPDATE**
Here is the full project source code if anyone is interested for anyone to git clone it:
https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/spring-integration-tcp-demo
I will try to put all suggested solutions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler with the DSL...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So55154418Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55154418Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow server() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(1234)))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .log()
                .handle((p, h) -> "OK")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow client() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234)))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    System.out.println("Received:" + p);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("client")
    public Runner runner(Gate gateway) {
        return new Runner(gateway);
    }

    public static class Runner {

        private final Gate gateway;

        public Runner(Gate gateway) {
            this.gateway = gateway;
        }

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
        public void run() {
            this.gateway.send("foo");
        }

    }

    public interface Gate {

        void send(String out);

    }

}
```

Or, get the reply from the Gate method...

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow client() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234)))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("client")
    public Runner runner(Gate gateway) {
        return new Runner(gateway);
    }

    public static class Runner {

        private final Gate gateway;

        public Runner(Gate gateway) {
            this.gateway = gateway;
        }

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
        public void run() {
            String reply = this.gateway.sendAndReceive("foo"); // null for timeout
            System.out.println("Received:" + reply);
        }

    }

    public interface Gate {

        @Gateway(replyTimeout = 5000)
        String sendAndReceive(String out);

    }
```

Bonus:

Consuming endpoints are actually comprised of 2 beans; a consumer and a message handler. The channel goes on the consumer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163586/tcpreceivingchanneladapter-vs-tcpsendingmessagehandler/55164225#55164225).

**EDIT**

An alternative, for a single bean for the client...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow client() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo", 
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234)))
            .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
            .handle((p, h) -> {
                System.out.println("Received:" + p);
                return null;
            })
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast response. Sorry to be such PIA but could such solution be possible where channel are exposed? Where I can actually see explicit commands `send()` and `receive()` in my client and server classes? Or would it be too difficult? Your solution is clearly is shorter in terms of code, but _simplicity_ is a bit subjective word.

Comment: I also noticed that both your solutions effectively splits Client into _request producing_ part (Gate) and _response processing_ part (handling lambda). Is that necessary? Can whole Client live in a single class, or even better, a single method? I was under impression that channels, if connected correctly, can deliver exactly this.

Comment: I added an alternative for the client, eliminating `Gate`. I am not sure what you mean in your first comment.

Comment: Gary, thank you very much! Still, my mind is still intrigued with solution based on outbound and inbound channels being handed over to Client to call `send()` on the `outboundChannel` and then blocking `receive()` on `inboundChannel`; reversely on Server side. Is it possible to configure something like `IntegrationFlows.from(outboundChannel).handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(..)).channel(inboundChannel).get()` for the client and `IntegrationFlows.from(inboundChannel).handle(Tcp.inboundGateway(..)).channel(outboundChannel).get()` for the server?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by adding a Queue `.channel()` after the outbound gateway and then `receive()`  from it. But my question is "why would you want to?". It adds complexity. One goal of the framework is to allow you to rise above low-level APIs and get rid of boilerplate code. If you want to code at a low level, why not just use the `Socket` APIs directly? Perhaps you have some unwritten business need that you are not explaining.

Comment: I am still learning the framework, exploring what can be done and what not. I've accepted your post but if you could be so kind and check the "channel solution"; client side seems to be working, implemented as suggested, but [server](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/spring-integration-tcp-demo/src/gsteways-and-channels-solution/heartbeat-server/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/espinosa/demo/sitcp/heartbeat/server/HeartbeatServerConfig.java) does [not even start](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/spring-integration-tcp-demo/src/gsteways-and-channels-solution/server_issue.md).

Comment: The admins here don't like extended commentary on questions/answers; I suggest you ask a new question with what you are trying to do; your current server implementation is completely wrong, but I don't have room here to explain the solution (and it's really not clear what you are trying to do).

Comment: Sure, kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329530/echo-socket-service-in-spring-integration-dsl-using-channels-and-gateways ..and yet again many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, here is one of the working solutions I made with help from Gary Russell. **All credits to Gary Russell**. [Full project source code here](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/spring-integration-tcp-demo/src/gateway-only-solution/).

Highlights:

- IntegrationFlows: Use only inbound and outbound Gateways.
- No Adapters or Channels needed; no ServiceActivators or Message Gate proxies.
- No need for ScheduledExecutor or Executors; client and server code got significatn
- IntegrationFlows directly calls methods on client class and server class; I like this type of explicit connection.
- Split client class on two parts, two methods: request producing part and response processing part; this way it can be better chained to flows.
- explicitly define clientConnectionFactory/serverConnectionFactory. This way more things can be explicitly configured later.

**HeartbeatClientConfig**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow heartbeatClientFlow(
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory,
        HeartbeatClient heartbeatClient) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(heartbeatClient::send,  e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(clientConnectionFactory))
            .handle(heartbeatClient::receive)
            .get();
}
```

**HeartbeatClient**

```
public class HeartbeatClient {
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HeartbeatClient.class);

    public GenericMessage<String> send() {
        log.info("Sending Heartbeat");
        return new GenericMessage<String>("status");
    }

    public Object receive(byte[] payload, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) { // LATER: use transformer() to receive String here
        String messageStr = new String(payload);
        if (messageStr.equals("OK")) {
            log.info("Heartbeat OK response received");
        } else {
            log.error("Unexpected message content from server: " + messageStr);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**HeartbeatServerConfig**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow heartbeatServerFlow(
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory,
        HeartbeatServer heartbeatServer) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Tcp.inboundGateway(serverConnectionFactory))
            .handle(heartbeatServer::processRequest)
            .get();
}
```

**HeartbeatServer**

```
public class HeartbeatServer {
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HeartbeatServer.class);

    public Message<String> processRequest(byte[] payload, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
        String messageStr = new String(payload);
        if (messageStr.equals("status")) {
            log.info("Heartbeat received");
            return new GenericMessage<>("OK");
        } else {
            log.error("Unexpected message content from client: " + messageStr);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```