# TcpReceivingChannelAdapter vs TcpSendingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ip

Why channel can be set on `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter`, the inbound adapter, but not on `TcpSendingMessageHandler`, the outbound adapter?

Why outbound adapter is called TcpSendingMessageHandler, why *handler*, not adapter?

One would intuitively expects that inbound adapter and outbound adapter would be "mirrors" of each other, just with different directions.

My question is variation of [Spring Integration - Inbound vs Outbound Channel Adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989581/spring-integration-inbound-vs-outbound-channel-adapters/29992267#29992267) question, but focused on *Spring Integration DSL* API and Tcp/Ip socket communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consuming endpoints (service activator, outbound channel adapter, outbound gateway etc). Consist of two beans, a Consumer (type depends on the channel type) and a message handler.

The channel goes on the consumer which calls the handler when it gets a message.

When using java configuration, the `@ServiceActivator` annotation triggers the creation of the consumer bean.

If you don't want to use annotations, add a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` to create the consumer (injecting the handler bean).